# Questions about game credits

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to know the name of the artist that created the box art for a game called Driller that was released in 1987

Here is the wikipedia page for the game:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Driller_(video_game)

Here is the cover art in question:

[image: Driller cover art]

Is such a question on topic for the site?

Comment: I don't know whether it's allowed. But i have your answer!

Comment: http://www.worldofspectrum.org/pub/sinclair/games-info/d/Driller.pdf -> the manual/ Instruction booklet

Comment: On pg 2 under acknowledgements "Steiner Lund" is listed for the cover. http://steinarlund.com/

Comment: Flagging as question asks for game identification.

Comment: @Timelord64 that's not the correct thing to do for a number of reasons. Firstly you shouldn't flag, you should vote to close. Secondly (and more importantly) this isn't a question asking for game ID - it's a question asking whether a specific type of game ID is on topic. And as it has proved eminently answerable and there was a visual artefact from the game, it almost certainly would be considered to be on topic by our standards.

Comment: @shanodin users below 3,000 reputation can flag questions to be closed before they've earned the rep to vote themselves. It places the question in the review queue and would be an imminently appropriate course of action were it not for the entirely accurate rest of your comment.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz sorry, my rep gain has been so glacial that I'd forgotten what rep is needed for what actions.

Comment: It's not strictly off topic that I know of: I wouldn't classify it as 'Game Identification' or even 'Developer Intent'. Personally I don't have a problem with these types of questions as they're usually relatively easily answerable, it's probably a case of either an encyclopedic/game history search, or even just sitting through the game credits. Not to mention some of our sibling sites like Movies & TV/Sci Fi & Fantasy etc allow (and thrive) on these types of questions. Having said that there'll probably be a backlash from the f̶u̶n̶ ̶p̶o̶l̶i̶c̶e̶ more avid curators of the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Questions like this are not off-topic, so feel free to ask your question. We actually have a few questions on the site already asking similiar things:

[Which level designer created the map Q2DM1 on Quake 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/80361/which-level-designer-created-the-map-q2dm1-on-quake-2)

[Who is the box art artist for Monster Maker 3 (Super Famicom)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106671/who-is-the-box-art-artist-for-monster-maker-3-super-famicom)

[Sam Fisher voice actor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128678/sam-fisher-voice-actor)

[Who are Gothic 2 english voice actors?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168649/who-are-gothic-2-english-voice-actors)

Most of these questions have downvotes, and I suspect yours would get some too, but your question won't be closed, so ask away.