# Is it okay to ask the name of a composition from a game?

Tags: discussion

I do not find anything in the help center. To clarify I want to know how a composition is named in a game. Can I ask this on Arcade Site?

Comment: When you say "composition", do you mean the name of a particular song in that game? Or do you mean composition in a different context?

Comment: Yes song. @Nzall

Comment: This has discussed previously [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14803/are-questions-about-names-of-in-game-music-on-topic), and the answer was "yes, this is fine". Cheers!

Comment: thanks I do not find it maybe because of wrong keywords ;D

Comment: @nobody Just be sure to tag it as `[insert-game-here]` and `[game-music-identification]` :)