# Is MIDI music from one game that originates from another game a valid artifact for the Game-Identification criteria?

Tags: discussion, game-identification

I've been playing through a custom mission for [descent-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/descent-1), an old 6DoF shooter from the 90s. The mission contains custom MIDI music, with a few tracks written by members of the game's community, and the rest supposedly pulled from other games, according to those members.

No one, not even the mission's author, can remember which games, but I have those MIDI files, and can share them as part of an identification question. **Is this too much of a stretch for this site's restrictions on Game Identification?** I have no real proof that the MIDI files are from other games, aside from someone's words.

<sub>Link to main site question that this meta was raised for: [Where are these two video game songs from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/400134/where-are-these-two-video-game-songs-from)</sub>

Comment: Does this provide an answer? https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14803/are-questions-about-names-of-in-game-music-on-topic

Comment: @TimmyJim it does clear things up, but I mostly wanted to make sure on the distinction of potential misinformation that they're game songs

Comment: I updated the title to be what I think is more appropriate so its easier to find/use for future reference.  I think this is what is being asked here if I'm not mistaken

Comment: cheers @TimmyJim, appreciate you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is within the tag scope.

As all media can only actually be verified *after* identification, the fact that—despite claims to the contrary—these MIDI files *may not actually* have been pulled from other games should not be an obstacle.

We've had [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification) questions for games that were merely props (see examples below): it takes an informed answer to point that out.

- [What's the video game in the movie "Big"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3577/whats-the-video-game-in-the-movie-big)
- [What is this medieval city-building game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343989/what-is-this-medieval-city-building-game/353949#353949)
- [What game was being played on The Office?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/341527/what-game-was-being-played-on-the-office)

Comment: cool, thanks Joachim and @TimmyJim :)